# The restriction of functions in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to a bouded open set $\Omega$ are in $H^1_0(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I'm new in studying PDEs and in the book I'm reading, a lot of times the author make the assertion: since $\|u_n\|_1$ is a bounded sequence in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then we can assume, taking a subsequence if necessary, that there exists $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $u_n$ converges weakly to $u$ and  $u_n\to u$ in $L_{loc}^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The first assertion is ok for me, but the second one is weird. My thinking is that if we take an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that its closure is compact, then the restriction of the $u_n$ to such a set is in $H^1_0(\Omega)$, so there exists a compact embedding of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ (apropriated $p$) so the assertion will be true if this was the case. But is this argument valid? The restriction of a function in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to a bounded open set $\Omega$ is in $H_0^1(\Omega)$?, i.e. if $v\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ implies that $v_{|\Omega}\in H_0^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: No, the restriction will almost never be in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. However the embedding $H^1(\Omega)\to L^p(\Omega)$ is compact if $\partial\Omega$ is "nice". Since we just want convergence in $L^p_{loc}$, we can take $\Omega$ to be balls of increasing radii, for which said compactness is valid.

Comment: @Jose27    Hmm Very Nice, thanks. Can you give me a reference that proves the compactness of such embedding?

Comment: It's in Evans' book on PDE, the idea is to use the compactness of the embedding $H_0^1(U)\to L^p(U)$ for a larger $U$ (i.e. $\overline{\Omega}\subset U$), using an extension operator $E:H^1(\Omega)\to H_0^1(U)$ (constructing this is where regularity of $\partial\Omega$ comes in).

Comment: @Jose27 thanks a lot!